# Ubuntu MATE ARM 64 update from 20.10

Tags: updates, raspberrypi, 20.10, ubuntu-mate, arm

How do I update from MATE 20.10 to the updated version on Rasp PI 4?

Comment: From System Information    -Computer-
Processor  : (Unknown)
Memory  : 8049MB (2092MB used)
Machine Type  : Single-board computer
Operating System  : Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from Ubuntu MATE 20.10 to 21.04 is possible by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

followed by reboot and one of the following commands

- in GUI mode

  ```
  update-manager -c
  ```
- in TTY mode

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Note: the above method is universal for both amd64 and RaspberryPi (*arm64* or *armhf*).

Comment: Apparently I got home to late to upgrade.  Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

I'll just wipe it all out and use something else. Its not a critical machine.          Thanks for your help regardless.